# How to order by column 1 equal column 2 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a set of columns for which I would like to order by set of 2 rows. For example as follow:

```
col1  col2

1     4
2     5
3     6
4     1
5     2
6     3
```

Desired output:

```
col1  col2

1     4
4     1
2     5
5     2
3     6
6     3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DKramer not sure to be clear on that. I felt the problem is well explained with the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must sort by the smallest of the columns first and the largest next:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col1 ELSE col2 END,
         CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col2 ELSE col1 END
```

Most databases support functions like MySql's `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` which simplify the code:

```
ORDER BY LEAST(col1, col2),
         GREATEST(col1, col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select records from a table but would like to see them sorted according to two columns, you can do so with ORDER BY. This clause comes at the end of your SQL query.

```
Sort by multiple column : ORDER BY column1 DESC, column2
```

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY col1 ASC;             -- ASCending is default
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY col1 DESC;            -- DESCending
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2;      -- col1 DESC then col2 ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your SQL sentence must contain next ORDER BY clause:

```
ORDER BY col1 + col 2 ASC, col1 ASC
```

will work

Comment: Except that it won't correctly sort these pairs `(1, 4) (2, 3) (3, 2) (4, 1)`